# How do I create a static constant closure?

Tags: rust

### Background

I have a struct that stores a couple of references to closures

```
struct FnThing<'a, F: Fn()> {
    f: &'a F,
}
```

I want to implement the `Default` trait for `FnThing` where `f` has default value of a no-op `||{}` function.

Since `f` is a reference, I plan to accomplish this by creating a static no-op closure function so that I can set the defualt value as

```
impl<'a, F: Fn()> Default for FnThing<'a, F> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { f: &NO_OP }
    }
}
```

### First attempt

```
static NO_OP: impl Fn = ||{};
```

rust complains that

```
`impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in const types
```

Fair enough

### Second attempt

```
static NO_OP: dyn Fn() = || {};
```

Now it complains that

```
the size for values of type `(dyn Fn() + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

OK, for unknown size, I should use the heap

### Third attempt

```
static NO_OP: Box<dyn Fn()> = Box::new(|| {});
```

Now it complains

```
`(dyn Fn() + Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

I don't care about multithreading atm, but it would still be nice if my code was thread safe in case I do in the future.  Though I fail understand why this isn't thread safe.

### Fourth attempt

Why not just use a simple function pointer?

```
static NO_OP: fn() = || {};

impl<'a, F: Fn()> Default for FnThing3<'a, F> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { f: NO_OP }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work since `fn()` and `F: Fn()` are different types.  Following [this answer](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/handy-way-to-convert-a-fn-function-pointer-to-an-fn-closure/34045/3), I try

```
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            f: (Box::new(NO_OP) as Box<dyn Fn()>).as_ref(),
        }
    }
```

but it still gives me the error

```
expected `&F`, found `&dyn Fn()`
```

### Question

I'm out of ideas...
**How do I create a static constant closure?**

Comment: *"Though I fail understand why this isn't thread safe"* – trait objects implement tha named traits **only**! Since you did not include `Send` or `Sync` your trait object doesn't implement them and so isn't threadsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Your problem right now is that you're trying to get a generic `F: impl Fn()`. You can just not write that, since you can't have a default over every generic type. So just `impl Default` for the case where `F` is just `fn()`, like so:

```rust
struct FnThing<'a, F: Fn()> {
    f: &'a F,
}

static NO_OP: fn() = || {};

impl<'a> Default for FnThing<'a, fn()> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        FnThing { f: &NO_OP }
    }
}
```

I think this is the what you want. Let me know if it works the way you want!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I knew I was missing something obvious!  I suppose there's no way to make this work if `FnThing` took `FnMut()` instead right?  
`struct FnThing<'a, F: FnMut()> { f: &'a mut F }`

Comment: Yeah that's not possible as it would imply shared mutable state. Instead of `&mut F` you would need something like `Arc<Mutex<F>>` I think. But if you don't generally need shared mutable state then it seems unnecessary to do this to just implement `Default`.

Comment: It would be idiomatic to just drop the reference alltogether and store the `F` directly, note that's *strictly* more general because [`&F: Fn()` for `F: Fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#impl-Fn%3CA%3E-for-%26F). That way you can also restrict `FnThing` to `FnMut` and don't need to changle a thing about it or it's `Default` implementation (because `FnMut` is a supertrait of `Fn` so everey `Fn` does also implement `FnMut`).