# Default closure arguments via arg struct pattern

Tags: rust

I have the following function `do_a_b`

```
fn do_a_b(mut a: impl FnMut(), mut b: impl FnMut()) {
    a();
    b();
}

fn main() {
    let do_a = || println!("Doing A!");
    do_a_b(do_a, || println!("Doing B!"))
}
```

I want to allow `do_a_b` to accept default arguments.  Since Rust does not support this, I plan to do this by using the [arg struct pattern](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fi6nov/comment/fkfhwnc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).  Specifically, I want to be able to only specify one of the parameters, and be able to use `..Default::default()` to fill out the rest, where it defaults to a no-op function `||{}`.

Here's my attempt

```
struct Args<A: FnMut(), B: FnMut()> {
    pub a: A,
    pub b: B,
}

fn do_a_b<A: FnMut(), B: FnMut()>(mut args: Args<A, B>) {
    (args.a)();
    (args.b)();
}

fn main() {
    let do_a = || println!("Doing A!");
    let args = Args {
        a: do_a,
        b: || println!("Doing B!"),
    };
    do_a_b(args);
}
```

So far so good.  But the tricky part is implementing `Default`

```
static NO_OP: fn() = || {};

impl Default for Args<fn(), fn()> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: NO_OP,
            b: NO_OP,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let do_a = || println!("Doing A!");
    let args = Args {
        a: do_a,
        ..Default::default() // this doesn't actually work
    };
    do_a_b(args);
}
```

The problem is `..Default::default()` doesn't actually work since the `Default` trait is only defined for `<fn(), fn()>` so any supplied closure will not satisfy the trait bound and hence won't have `Default` available.

My question is how best should I go about creating this arg struct?

If this is a limitation for Rust, is there an RFC that can potentially make this possible?

(This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78142056/3177701))

Comment: As I've already commented below your other question, `unsafe` and `static mut` are wholly unnecessary for your problem, just remove `&'a mut` from `A` (akin to how you've defined `B` not sure why you're going 2 distinct routes)

Comment: `..Default::default()` can't work, because you're trying to change the type, (the generic parameters) and `..Default::default()` can't do that.

Comment: [Here is a version without `unsafe`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a78b4c8620e7db20137066b9fec00d5e)

Comment: @cafce25 But what if I don't want to own the closure and only want to borrow it?  I'd ideally want to be able to do this for both owning closures and borrowed closures.

Comment: This [**is** the version that works for owned and borrowed closures](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a5b9fd5e68de3789084221af42b62dd)… there are implementations [`FnMut<A> for &mut F where F: FnMut<A>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#impl-FnMut%3CA%3E-for-%26mut+F) and similar for `Fn`

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for the info, I didn't know about that `&mut FnMut` was redundant in this situation.  I've updated the code to better focus on the `Default` part of the question

Answer (score 0):

> If this is a limitation for Rust, is there an RFC that can potentially make this possible?

It seems with [RFC2528](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2528-type-changing-struct-update-syntax.html), I'll at least be able to define a static `DefaultArg` object and instantiate my specific `Arg` with the [Struct Update Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax)

```
static DEFAULT_ARG: Args<fn(), fn()> = Args { a: NO_OP, b: NO_OP };

let arg = Arg {
  a: || println!("My own thing"),
  ..DEFAULT_ARG
}
```

which is close enough

[playground using nightly with RFC2528 enabled](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b32b80df0552efd03394312cadcd257)